# navigation issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, spo

I am facing this issue that, it's disabled
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently in the site settings interface of a top-level site, the top-level site doesn’t have a parent site so it can't display the same navigation items as a subsite site.

You can enable this option in a subsite. If you are in a subsite, it will display as below:
[image]

Comment: okay I see, but how can i quick edit in the navigation without opening a new page

Answer (score 0):

For Site collection does not have the parent, so navigation will not inherit from parent. But in the subsite this option must be enabled because subsite have the parent site